# MySQL Syntax error when updating scores

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE game_score SET 
    score=
        (CASE name 
         WHEN 'player1' THEN score+50 
         WHEN 'player2' THEN score+47 
    END)
WHERE name IN 
('player1', 
 'player2')
```

score+50 and score+47 makes a syntax error, it works if I do `WHEN 'player1' THEN '50'` or `WHEN 'player2' THEN '47'`. But I need to add on to the score value.

Comment: add **outside** of `CASE`

Comment: It tested your query and there is no syntax error in what you showed. I assume the actual query that produced the error is different. When you ask questions about SQL, you should share the actual query, the actual error, and the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table affected by the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
UPDATE game_score SET 
    score= score + 
        (CASE name 
         WHEN 'player1' THEN 50 
         WHEN 'player2' THEN 47 
    END)
WHERE name IN 
('player1', 
 'player2')
```